# What does '1-NN is statistically inconsistent' mean?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, classification, mathematical-statistics, k-nearest-neighbour

I am confused about the fact "1-NN is statistically inconsistent". Why and how??

References
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1712.02369.pdf

https://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/~karyeh/bayes-consistent-1nn.pdf

https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/a08f/133198a845589e6801e2125dc973d2652d66.pdf

( in introduction)

Thanks advance for any help :).

Comment: What is the source of this quote?

Comment: What does "statically inconsistent" mean? This phrase is extremely rare and doesn't appear in any statistics book or journal AFAIK.

Comment: See references.

Comment: The references don't use that phrase, but they do use "statistically inconsistent:" perhaps that's what you mean.

Comment: "1-NN is statistically inconsistent, i.e., its prediction accuracy
plateaus early as sample size n increases"

Comment: @missRan You should fix the typos in your question. It will help people understand what you mean and what you would like to know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In machine learning, we sometimes use this terminology, e.g. in [these notes](https://www.shivani-agarwal.net/Teaching/E0370/Aug-2011/Lectures/16.pdf):

An algorithm is "statistically consistent" in a hypothesis class $\mathcal H$ for a distribution $P$ is one that whose error rate converges in probability to the minimum error rate over $\mathcal H$ as the number of samples goes to infinity. An algorithm is "Bayes consistent" for a distribution $P$ if it converges to the Bayes error rate, the best possible error rate. (Saying these properties hold "universally" implies they hold for all distributions $P$.)

The 1-NN algorithm is often said to be consistent only if the problem is *realizable*, i.e. the Bayes error is zero. As we saw in your [other recent question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/436258/the-expected-error-of-1-nearest-neighbor-1-nn-on-large-or-infinite-dataset), it is also Bayes-consistent when the Bayes error rate is 50%, but that's not very interesting since *any* predictor is Bayes-consistent in that case.

In Cover and Hart (1967), [*Nearest neighbor pattern classification*](https://doi.org/10.1109/TIT.1967.1053964), they give the following example (section VII): let $X \mid Y = 1$ have density $f_1$, and $X \mid Y = 2$ have density $f_2$, where
$$
f_1(x) = \begin{cases}
2 x & \text{if } 0 \le x \le 1 \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\qquad
f_2(x) = \begin{cases}
2 - 2 x & \text{if } 0 \le x \le 1 \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
.$$

[image: Plot of the triangular densities from this example]

The expected error probability here with $n$ samples turns out to be, after "a lengthy but straightforward calculation,"
$$
\frac13 + \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}
\to \frac13
.$$
But the Bayes error rate is the error rate of the predictor that says $2$ for $x < \frac12$ and $1$ for those above:
\begin{multline}
\frac12 \Pr(X > \tfrac12 \mid Y=2)
+ \frac12 \Pr(X<\tfrac12 \mid Y=1)
\\= \frac12 \int_0^{\frac12} f_1(x) \,\mathrm{d}x + \frac12 \int_{\frac12}^1 f_2(x) \,\mathrm{d}x
= \frac14
.\end{multline}
Thus the 1-NN expected error rate is always worse than the Bayes error rate.
Thus 1-NN is not Bayes consistent for this problem. It's also not statistically consistent for the hypothesis class of, say, locally constant predictors.

Comment: OK, in order to say the 1-NN is statistically consistent should converge to the Bayes error rate almost surely (not double). 1-NN is statistically consistent just in two cases when the Bayes error rate is zero (when no overlapping between two classes) and when the Bayes error rate is 0.50 (two classes are totally overlapping), is that true ?!.

Comment: The usual definition is convergence in probability, not almost surely, but yes to the first bit. To the second: I think it might actually be Bayes-consistent for _some_ distributions with nontrivial Bayes error, but I'm not 100% sure. It's certainly not universally Bayes consistent, as the example above shows.

Comment: Universally Bayes consistent if the classifier is Bayes consistent on all data distribution. That's true?!

Comment: Yep that's right.

Comment: you helped me a lot, many thanks :)